# Obscure the whole screen (status bar included)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I try to obscure the entire screen to have a focus on some elements when clicking on a button.

[What i'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU0r2.png)

I'm looking for the same shadow created when a BottomSheet appear.

I tried to set a layout covering my entire view but obviously the status bar doesn't change. (I animate alpha on click)

I tried to use `android:statusBarColor`, `android:windowTranslucentStatus`, `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` and `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` but unfortunately my toolbar appear behind the status bar.

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MxdK.png)

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you are looking for exactly?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

Comment: I eddited my question to add some images.